# Salesforce CPQ error when marking Renewal Quoted on Contract

Tags: apex, cpq

When attempting to mark 'Renewal Quoted' on a contract within Salesforce, I'm getting an error stemming from managed Salesforce CPQ code:

Error:Apex trigger SBQQ.ContractAfter caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: SBQQ.ContractAfter: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Class.SBQQ.RenewalQuoteGenerator.addAsset: line 741, column 1

I've narrowed it down the problem to being the subscriptions on the contract. If I delete the subscriptions from the Contract, I'm able to successfully mark 'Renewal Quoted' on the contract. Any idea as to why the above error is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the subscriptions had a SBQQ__RequiredById__c value that referenced an asset in which the SBQQ__RootAsset__c field on that asset was referencing an asset from a different account than the subscription.

Comment: @user34302457, make you answer as correct, so this question doesn't show up anymore